# how to parse values from JSON.stringified data in a text component sent from a different page

Tags: json, react-native, react-router-native

with regard to this tutorial "React Router Native - Passing Data" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdOWxoH3HLg by @benawad user:4272160 
I can't figure out how to extract bob or 5 from 
`{"val1:"bob","val2":5}` 
from the stringified string data in `<Text>JSON.stringify(location.state)}</Text>` 
when passing data between pages

I've tried to contact @benawad through a comment, I've searched google and here for similar but found nil relevant. I tried a regex unsuccessfully but there has to be a better way anyway...

code is at https://github.com/benawad/react-router-native-example/tree/1_advanced

```
// Home.js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";

export default ({ history }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>This is the home page</Text>
    <Button title="change page" onPress={() =>
    history.push("/products", {val1: "bob", val2: 5})
    />
  </View>
);


// Products.js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";

 export default ({ history, location }) => (
  <View>
  <Text>Product 1</Text>
  <Text>Product 2</Text>
  <Text>{JSON.stringify(location.state)}</Text>
  <Button title="change page" onPress={() => history.push("/")}/>
  </View>
);
```

I thought about trying to JSON.parse the stringified data. No joy. I tried location.state.val but just got

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'location.state.val')
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve or solve? your code snippet is not like the github code?

Comment: Where are you running JSON.parse?

Comment: @Meabed I just want to get bob out of {"val1:"bob","val2":5} but the trouble is that it is stringified and inside a <Text> component in Products.js   nb snippet is  the implemention from the video tutorial before the button was implemented as a separate component changePageButton..

Comment: @hong develop given that  {"val1:"bob","val2":5}  is stringified & sitting inside a <Text> component in Products.js how do I get at it?     nb JSON.parse not run anywhere at all - it was just an idea to parse a string back to an object in order to get at bob or 5 but I could not figure out how to do it

Comment: is it solved yet, or should i dig it on for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass state through the `history` api. Change your `Home` component to

```
export default ({ history }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>This is the home page</Text>
    <Button title="change page" onPress={() => 
    history.push("/products", {val1: "bob", val2: 5)} />
  </View>
);
```

and then access `location.state.val1` and `location.state.val2` directly in your `Products` component.

See https://github.com/benawad/react-router-native-example/blob/1_advanced/ChangePageButton.js#L9 for the similar `history` line in the tutorial code.

The `JSON.stringify` used in the example code is just there as an illustration so that the entire `location.state` can be displayed in a `Text` element.

Comment: my point is that I get TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'location.state.val1')  doing it like that...

Comment: In your example code you are not passing any location state through the `history` api - did you update your `Home` component code to `history.push("/products", {val1: "bob", val2: 5})` instead of just `history.push("/products")`?

Comment: Sorry azundo. Yes I did that already. Unfortunately, I just copied & pasted the wrong bit of code when posting the question late last night. Duh...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to history object,

```
<Button title="change page" 
  onPress={() => history.push({
    pathname: '/',
    state: { locationData: JSON.stringify(location.state) } //JSON.stringify needed if you want to pass object otherwise don't use.
  })}
/>
```

In the component which is rendered with `/` route, you can access the props like,

```
{JSON.parse(props.location.state.locationData)}        //Functional component
{JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.locationData)}   //Class based component
```

**Note:** `JSON.parse` needed if object is being passed otherwise no need to use.